# WSGI: Can the iterable returned from the app be iterated from different threads?

Tags: python, multithreading, mod-wsgi, wsgi

From reading the WSGI specification in [PEP 3333](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3333/), it is not entirely clear to me if it guaranteed that the iterable returned from an application will be iterated on the same thread that run the application or even if all iteration steps are done on the same step (i.e. if the iterable has a thread affinity to the thread that returned it). I found some [discussion on the web-sig mailing list from 2005](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/web-sig/2005-December/001807.html) which says something to the effect of "not guaranteed but it would be bad if some server did it that way".

Also, in the [section on middleware](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3333/#middleware-handling-of-block-boundaries), the PEP says that "synchronous applications and servers can conspire to reduce the number of threads that are required to run a given number of application instances simultaneously" which would also imply that iteration may be done from different threads.

So my main question is: Are there any WSGI implementations that iterate the iterable returned from an WSGI application from different threads, esp. threads different from the one that called the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the more popular WSGI servers do and never heard of any others which do either.